# How a parent component look like if the child has <button> tag

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, vue-composition-api

Referring to the official documentation [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html), if a child components contains the following code:

```
<!-- MyComponent.vue -->
<script setup>
defineProps(['title'])
defineEmits(['update:title'])
</script>

<template>
<input
    type="text"
    :value="title"
    @input="$emit('update:title',   
    $event.target.value)"

  />
</template>
```

Then the parent component v-model should look like as follows:

```
<MyComponent v-model:title="bookTitle" />
```

My question, is what if a child component has a ‘button’ tag? As follows:

```
<button @click="say('hello')">Say    
hello</button>

<button @click="say('bye')">Say   
bye</button>
```

How would the parent component look like?

Comment: I don't understand your goal. You want to trigger something on parent component when click on button ?

Comment: @ZecKa I mean, in the parent component, I should do the following <MyComponent……/>, right? What should be included in that tag?”<MyComponent>

Comment: I you don't want to receive any event from your child just use <MyComponent />

Comment: @ZecKa I mean which model should I use? V-model or v-bind, is it clearer now?

Comment: Lol, no it's not clearer. I don't know if it's you or me lol. What's your goal ? You want to receive click event from the button to the parent component ?

Comment: @ZecKa oh sorry for the murky elucidation from my side.however, I know how to send an event from a child to parent component. Is there any other possibilities other than binding on the @click? For example, can v-model or v-bind be in use?!

Comment: Sorry but i really don't understand what's your issue here and what's you try to achieve... You know how to emit an event and you know how to use two way data binding...